How to show gridline at up?
I created show forecast of weather and I want to show gridlines (of temperature) at up. I tried something like this:
yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: true,
         color: "gray",
         lineWidth: 1,
         drawOnChartArea: true
      }

And too many other "solutions". But I still can't gridlines at up (everywhere). I see the gridline only at below of labels.
My version: 2.9.4.
Example: https://asteroid.vsevjednom.cz/
I want to see this lines: Remove Chart.js Gridline Overlap

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Please add the runable example inside the question

It's unclear what you want to achieve. I don't understand what you mean by "at up"; also you point to a stackoverflow post about tickmarks, but the chart on your site does have visible tickmarks for both x and y axis.

"at up" = everywhere.

If by any chance what you want to achieve is to draw the gridlines above the filled area of the chart, that I think cannot be achieved by any combination of options, since the filler plugin (for version 2.9.4) always draws on beforeDatasetsDraw and at that time the grid lines were already drawn. The only solution I can think of is to redraw the grid lines in a plugin, on the afterDatasetsDraw hook, see codepen example.

That is, if the standard and obvious solution, to set the backgroundColor of the dataset to a transparent color (e.g., rgba) is not convenient.

Thank you! I thought about afterDatasetsDraw too. But how to do it? How to show it every 5 lines (0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30...)?

I tested the code in the codepen with stepSize: 5 and with various other options from the source code of your site and it seems to work the same way. What happens when you add it that is not OK?

Thank you but I don't know how to write it. And I can't to find any solution: https://www.google.com/search?q=chart.js+%22afterDatasetsDraw%22+lines

I'm using stepSize: 5 at scales/yAxes/ticks - tick is the lowest but I don't know how to use it in  afterDatasetsDraw.

Solved!
data/datasets:
{
label: "10",
data: [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10],
backgroundColor: "transparent",
}, {
label: "20",
data: [20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20],
backgroundColor: "transparent",
}

I found a solution here: chart.js remove lower grid from mixed chart
